# Install my app in other Windows 8.1 device

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I develop my windows store application. For my testing, i have to install the developer licence in both my development device and testing device.

But after that, if i want to install this application in another device, is there any other way to do it? as the developer license will be expired every 1 month.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue with the develop license running out.

Comment: So? If the license expires, you just need to renew it. If it's only for testing purposes, that shouldn't be an issue. For long term deployment, push your app to the store, or use side-loading (good luck with that...)

Answer (score 0):

With developer licence you can register three device; install licence on device and install your app with visual studio.

Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508(v=vs.105).aspx you can read:

> If you have a developer account, you can register three devices to use
>   for app development, and you can publish apps in the Windows Phone
>   Store.